# "Multiple" Foreign Key

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I have tables:

- MUSICIANS (musician_id, ...)
- PROGRAMMERS (programmer_id, ...)
- COPS (cop_id, ...)

Then I'm going to have a specific table

- RICH_PEOPLE (rich_person_id, ...)

where `rich_person_id` is either `musician_id`, `programmer_id` or `cop_id`. (Assume that all the `musician_id`s, `programmer_id`s, `cop_id`s are **different**.)

Is it possible to directly create a Foreign Key on the field `rich_person_id`?

P.S. I would like the database to

- ensure that there is a record of either `MUSICIANS`, `PROGRAMMERS` or `COPS` with the same id as the new `RICH_PEOPLE` record's `rich_person_id` **before inserting** it into `RICH_PEOPLE`
- deleting from either `MUSICIANS`, `PROGRAMMERS` or `COPS` would fail (or require cascade deletion) if there a `RICH_PEOPLE` record with the same id

P.P.S. I wouldn't like

- creating an extra table like `POSSIBLY_RICH_PEOPLE` with the only field `possibly_rich_person_id`
- creating triggers

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: This is a problem that stems from not normalizing properly. Depending on the hidden columns of the three tables (musicians, programmers and cops) you probably just want one table `person` that includes the common columns for all three types of people. If you don't have any "occupation specific" attributes, just include an "occupation" column that identifies what that person does. If not, create tables that contain the occupation specific attributes and link it to the person table. This could be done using inheritance of plain foreign keys.

Comment: The table rich_people is also not necessary, just create a column `is_rich` in the `person` table.

Comment: ... and there *could* exist rich musicians. so, a column `is_musician` could also be possible.

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? Please get rid of the rest. Show your code in a [mre] & ask about where you got stuck.. Be more clear--if what you want might not be a FK, you can't use "FK" to say what you want. You will be asking a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create three nullable foreign keys, one to each foreign table. Then use a `CHECK` constraint to ensure only one value is not null at any given time.

For example:

```
create table rich_people (
  rich_person_id int primary key not null,
  musician_id int references musicians (musician_id),
  programmer_id int references programmers (programmer_id),
  cop_id int references cops (cop_id),
  check (musician_id is not null and programmer_id is null and cop_id is null
      or musician_id is null and programmer_id is not null and cop_id is null
      or musician_id is null and programmer_id is null and cop_id is not null)
);
```

This way, referential integrity will be ensured at all times. Deletions will require cascade deletion or other strategy to keep data integrity.

Comment: In Postgres, the check constraint can be simplified to `check ( num_nonnulls(musician_id, programmer_id, cop_id) = 1) `

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I do like PostgreSQL. Always one step ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You do this in a somewhat different way:

- Create a table `people` with a `person_id`.
- Use this key as the primary key (*and* foreign key) for each of your occupation tables.
- Use this key as the primary key (*and* foreign key) for your `rich_people` table.

Postgres supports a concept called ["inheritance"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-inheritance.html), which facilitates this type construct.  Your occupation tables can "inherit" columns from `people`.